# when to use dark array vs dask dataframe in one-hot-encoding ML workloads

Tags: python, dask

I have a dataset which is a huge, short and fat matrix (~4000 x 20,000,000).  I am thinking dask might be a good solution for me.  However, I want to make sure I can encode it to a one-hot matrix.  I looked at the options in dask-ml and they seem to always need a dask dataframe. However, it seems really odd and possible like it would cause a lot of overhead to create a dataframe with 20 million columns. Is it easier just to use a dask array and somehow use apply on axis to convert each column to 1-hot?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that dask-ml also supports dask.arrays

However, the algorithms for both dask-ml and dask.dataframe parallelize across rows, not columns, so neither may be a good fit.

I suspect that your matrix is likely very sparse.  Regardless of which path you take I recommend looking into sparse matrices, such as those in the [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), or [sparse](http://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/) packages.  The latter package is compatible with dask.array, which does support chunking along any dimension, not just rows.

Comment: Yes, I was using sparse previously when my data was smaller. The array isn't super sparse in 1-hot format (5-10% data).  In this case, the original data when in dense format is 640 Gigs, when I do one hot is increasing by 8-10x which then if held in sparse still puts me around 600 Gigs. Unfortunately the encoder I want to use to put in 1-hot, it says in the documentation it only works with dataframes.  (http://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/generated/dask_ml.preprocessing.DummyEncoder.html#dask_ml.preprocessing.DummyEncoder)

Comment: I would assume they often computed  in terms of blocksize for dask-ml since they are stored that way, not explicitly by rows or columns. Since that is how other libraries work (e.g. scalapack, etc).

Comment: I want to use the partialfit/incremental learning functionality so across columns is fine as long as it doesn't use all the rows.